# Get smallest date for each element in access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, many-to-many

So I have a table containing different elements and dates.
It basically looks like this:

```
actieElement    beginDatum
1               1/01/2010
1               1/01/2010
1               10/01/2010
2               1/02/2010
2               3/02/2010
```

What I now need is the smallest date for every actieElement.
I've found a solution using a simple GROUP BY statement, but that way the query loses its scope and you can't change anything anymore.

Without the GROUP BY statement I get multiple dates for every actieElement because certain dates are the same.

I thought of something like this, but it also does not work as it would give the subquery more then 1 record:

```
SELECT s1.actieElement, s1.begindatum
FROM tblActieElementLink AS s1
WHERE (((s1.actieElement)=(SELECT TOP 1 (s2.actieElement)
          FROM tblActieElementLink  s2
          WHERE s1.actieElement = s2.actieElement
          ORDER BY s2.begindatum ASC)));
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'ou can't change anything anymore' and what exactly are you trying to do

Comment: MS Access doesn't allow update queries on joins (either explicit or implicit), where one side of the join is not updateable. We have used temporary tables in those situations; no other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT s1.actieElement, s1.begindatum
FROM tblActieElementLink AS s1
WHERE s1.begindatum =(SELECT MIN(s2.begindatum)
          FROM tblActieElementLink  s2
          WHERE s1.actieElement = s2.actieElement
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.actieElement, T1.beginDatum
  FROM tblActieElementLink AS T1
       INNER JOIN (
                   SELECT T2.actieElement, 
                          MIN(T2.beginDatum) AS smallest_beginDatum
                     FROM tblActieElementLink AS T2
                    GROUP
                       BY T2.actieElement
                  ) AS DT1
          ON T1.actieElement = DT1.actieElement
             AND T1.beginDatum = DT1.smallest_beginDatum;
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a DISTINCT clause to your SELECT.

Comment: And you're suggesting this will enhance editability? Seriously?

Comment: Editability?  What are you talking about?  I was just trying to provide assistance to solving the problem.